# Optimize performance of complex GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

Is there a way to optimize the following query. It takes about 11s:

```
SELECT 
    concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), '000') as datetime, 
    TRUNCATE(SUM(royalty_price*conversion_to_usd*
             (CASE WHEN sales_or_return = 'R' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)*
             (CASE WHEN royalty_currency = 'JPY' THEN .80 
                   WHEN royalty_currency in ('AUD', 'NZD') THEN .95 ELSE 1 END) )
    ,2) as total_in_usd
FROM 
    sales_raw 
GROUP BY
    date 
ORDER BY
    date ASC
```

Doing an explain I get:

```
1   SIMPLE  sales_raw   index   NULL    date    5   NULL    735855  NULL
```

Comment: It's an aggregation. Nothing really to do but scan the whole table since there's no WHERE clause. In that case, it's a question of I/O performance and CPU performance (for your expressions). Can you filter on a set of (indexed) dates so you only need to read a portion of the table?

Comment: @NWest thank you for the response. Could you please show an example of what you mean by "filter on a set of indexed dates" ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the question in the comment.  It formats better here:

An example of filtering on a set of indexed dates means to do something like this:

```
where date >= AStartDateVariable
and date < TheDayAfterAnEndDateVariable
```

If there is no index on the date field, create one.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to speed this up.  You seem to have an index on `date`.  What is happening is that the rows are read in the index, then each row is looked up.  If the data is not ordered by the date field, then this might not be optimal, because the reads will be on, essentially, random pages.  In the case where the original table does *not* fit into memory, this results in a condition called "page thrashing".  A record is needed, the page is read from memory (displacing another page in the memory cache), and the next read probably also results in a cache miss.

To see if this is occuring, I would suggest one of two things.  (1) Try removing the index on `date` or switching the `group by` criterion to `concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), '000')`.  Either of these should remove the index as a factor.

From your additional comment, this is not occuring, although the benefit of the index appears to be on the small side.

(2) You can also expand the index to include all the tables used in the query.  Besides date, the index would need to contain royalty_price, conversion_to_usd, sales_or_return, and royalty_currency.  This would allow the index to fully satisfy the query, without looking up additional infromation in the pages.

You can also check with your DBA to be aure that you have a large enough page cache that matches your hardware capabilities.

Comment: For #2, do you mean a composite index with all those fields? Or a unique index for each?

Comment: It looks like doing #1 slows down the query by about 20%.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and upvoters: please note that in principle the index on date is desirable (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html, first paragraph). #2 can not help since the first index on date is all that is needed to retrieve the additional fields. More indexes would be most likely ignored by the optimizer since they are intended for finding the rows with the data, not the data itself. But perhaps you can tell a case, in RDMBS, where an index is used only to find the data.

Comment: @koriander . . . In this case, it would be doing a tight-index scan, but would require fetching pages for the additional columns not in the index.  My answer was not clear (and I revised it) but having a table larger than memory can result in page-thrashing.  If the table fits into memory, then this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple group by query which does not even involve joins. I would expect the problem to lie on the functions you are using.

Please start with a simple query just retrieving date and the sum of conversion_to_usd. Check performance and build up the query step by step always checking performance. It should not take long to spot the culprit.

Concats are usually slow operations but I wonder if truncate after sum might be confusing the optimiser. The 2nd case could be replaced by relying on a join with a table of currency codes and respective percentages, but it's not obvious that it makes a big difference. First spot the culprit operation.

You could also store the values with the correct amount but that introduces a denormalisation.